# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder, imagecreatefromjpg

I am getting this error for all of my jpg/png/svg files when running the "yarn electron ." command for my project. My react app is working perfectly, in my electron web app everything is working except for the pictures that are not loading. I have no idea what the issue is. Using electron-builder version=22.9.1 os=19.6.0, electron v11.3.0, macOs catalina version 10.15.7